# Team Foundation Version Control using Azure DevOps Services and Azure DevOps Server

Tags: azure-devops, tfvc

I was wondering if it's possible to have TFVS using Azure DevOps Services or TFVS using Azure DevOps Server. Which one is better and how to connect TFVS using Azure DevOps Server. I have experience in connecting it with Azure DevOps Services but I'm wondering the differences with Azure DevOps Server. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible; TFVC is exactly the same between the two. You connect to a TFVC repo in Azure DevOps exactly the same way you'd connect to an on-prem instance.